# Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used

Tags: protractor

I have used restartBrowserBetweenTests: true in the config file.

First test case executes properly and browser reopens after the first test.

Then it will execute till the last step in beforeEach method.

When it tries to execute the second i am getting `Message:Failed: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used`

```
beforeEach(function()
    {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get(url);
    element(by.id('identity')).sendKeys(usrname);
    element(by.id('password')).sendKeys(pwd);
    element(by.name('submit')).click();
    element(by.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/p/a[1]')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);
    });


it('Login Test',function()
{
    var title=browser.getTitle();
    expect(title).toEqual('Welcome to Home Page.');
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);  
});

it('Create a new lead',function()
{       
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);
    lead.click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried sample code similar to the structure of code you posted and it worked. Can you try following snippet and if it works then something is going wrong in your code.

```
beforeEach(async function() {

    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
    console.log('hi');
 });

it('Login Test',function()
{
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);  
});

it('Create a new lead',function()
{       
    browser.driver.sleep(4000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin for your time. Mine is a Non AJ application. Will that make any difference?

Comment: Your given code at above can work, but once you use `element` api, it will fail. For short, the `element` is a type of `ElementFindArray` which wrap a `browser` , but `restartBrowserBetweenTests` not replace it with the new `browser`,  when `element` api invoked on the second test,  the browser in `element` api still point to the preview webdriver instance which had `quit()`